# Getting context in adapter

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, adapter, android-context

I'm wondering how to get context in adapter?

I'm trying to use SharedPreferences in my adapter, however I need to get context so it will work.

```
public class ImgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ColorMatrixColorFilter cf;
    String Question = Question.Pref;


    public ImgAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
        matrix.setSaturation(0); //0 means grayscale
        cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(Question, context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
       ---- "I'm trying to use SharedPreferences in there" ----
        ImageView imageView;

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        if(Question.answered){
            imageView.setColorFilter(cf);
            imageView.setAlpha(175);
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    public static Integer[] mThumbIds = 
    {
        R.drawable.question1,
        R.drawable.question2,
    };

}
```

When I try to do this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context) {
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(Question, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I get `The type ImgAdapter must implement the inherited abstract method Adapter.getView(int, View, ViewGroup)`

Is it possible to do this? if so can someone help me?

Comment: why can't you just use `mContext` ?

Comment: @blackbelt Because I tried and the app crashed

Comment: and why it is crashing ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the stacktrace that you get when you try to use mContext.

Comment: Why do not inflate any thing ?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct type of `Context` to the Adapter? If you are creating an instance of the Adapter from an Activity, you need to pass the keyword `this` to the Adapter's constructor. If it is from a fragment, you need to pass `getActivit()` to the constructor.

Comment: I tried what Ragnar answered, now it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent,
>   Context context) { SharedPreferences pref =
>   context.getSharedPreferences(Question, context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Because you have wrong method signature. You have one extra parameter `Context` that no matches with method signature inherited from super class.

Look you have this:

```
public View getView(int po, View row, ViewGroup parent, Context context) { ... }
```

It has to be:

```
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) { ... }
```

Remove Context parameter from method signature and it'll work. Just note that you are able to access your mContext variable and you can do that:

```
SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(...);
```

Hope it will help you to solve your problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not implement getView() method in this way.

You all-ready  have context at top

```
 private Context mContext;
```

Use this context in your preference like bellow

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(Question, mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

mContext@Stav L Replace

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(Question, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences pref =  mContext.getSharedPreferences(Question, mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are passing the correct type of Context to the Adapter? If you are creating an instance of the Adapter from an Activity, you need to pass the keyword this to the Adapter's constructor. If it is from a fragment, you need to pass getActivit() to the constructor.

From Activity:

```
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
```

From Fragment:

```
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
```

You need to check what kind of context you're sending. The above should work perfectly fine. Ensure that you're using one of the above and not `getApplicationContext` or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't need any Context reference in the getView() method, because it's already providing you with a Context. See the parent? This IS your Context:

```
parent.getContext()
```

is all you need. :-)

Another major point: Your getView() implementation seems to be incredibly inefficient, if not to say wrong. Please use ViewHolder pattern and see this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70